# Performing bulk arithmetic operations on python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I have a list of integers and I want to perform operations like addition, multiplication, floor division on every element of list slice (sub array) or at certain indexes (eg. range(start, end, jump) ) efficiently. The number being added or multiplied by each element of list slice is constant (say 'k').

For example:

```
    nums = [23, 44, 65, 78, 87, 11, 33, 44, 3]
    for i in range(2, 7, 2):
        nums[i] //= 2 # here 2 is the constant 'k'
    print(nums)
    >>>    [23, 44, 32, 78, 43, 11, 16, 44, 3]
```

I have to perform these operations several times on different slices/ranges and the constant 'k' varies for different slices/ranges. The obvious way to do this is to run a for loop and modify the value of elements, but that isn't fast enough. You can do this efficiently by using a numpy array because it supports bulk assignment/modification but I am looking for a way to do this in pure python.

Comment: How fast is *fast enough*? How big is `nums` in reality or how many operations? Your current code is pretty efficient I think

Comment: What's the problem of using numpy?

Comment: Anything that shows a significant performance boost (> 20%) is fast enough for me. There are 1 million elements in my integer list and I have to modify values at indexes of the form range(start, end, start).

Comment: looks you want to have nums as bigger range. if not the tried code looks ok only. numpy has efficient features, you can consider that as well

Comment: You may have found the most efficient way in pure Python. Have you heard of [Cython](http://cython.org/)? Is it an option?

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid the for loop is the following:

```
>>> nums = [23, 44, 65, 78, 87, 11, 33, 44, 3]
>>> nums[2:7:2] = [x//2 for x in nums[2:7:2]]
>>> nums
[23, 44, 32, 78, 43, 11, 16, 44, 3]
```

Comment: You're not avoiding the for loop, you're just using list comprehension and making unnecessary copies of list slice. This is even more inefficient than my code.

Comment: You're right. With timeit.timeit and a large array, it takes about twice the time. Which surprises me, because a list comprehension does not return to user-level code until the list has been built. I expected that to be more efficient. You learn something new every day :-)